# Why was question 311149 marked off-topic and closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-request

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/311149/any-televisions-that-support-windows-network-projector-protocol) was marked as off-topic. This of course includes a link to the FAQ which actually I had read before asking my question. None of the other Stack Exchange sites seemed to apply.

The part of the FAQ that allows the question and makes it on-topic is:

> and it is not about …
>
> ```
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones,
>   except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> ```

Asking about television models that include Remote Desktop support is obviously exception 3: electronic devices that interface with your computer.

Comment: Because the clause implies the problem is fixable on the computer side of things. Your problem is not and on top of things is a shopping-recommendation

Comment: One thing that people seem to miss is that *there are questions for which there is **no** appropriate SE website*. This does not mean you should post said question on the site that is "closest".

Comment: It was closed because you are shopping for a TV

Answer (score 7):

You're asking for a TV (shopping recommendation) which features Remote Desktop application ( not *interfacing* to the computer).

Comment: Agree. "not interfacing to the computer"

Comment: Remote Desktop isn't interfacing to a computer? Strange definition there.

Comment: Interfacing over the network, no. Interfacing in the context of electronic devices and smartphones means attaching and communicating with them via USB or some other native connection. (Making sure they show up in Device Manager or in `/dev`, making sure the right COM ports are created on the PC side if needed, etc.). In the context of this question, that would be making sure RDP is working on the PC and that the PC can listen for network connections. Anything more than that is outside the scope of SuperUser.